# Refresh adapter in a Fragment after DialogFragment dbflow insert

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have an activity that has 3 fragments on it with Tabs, one of them is called "TaskFragment".

In my main Activity i only load the fragments.
In TaskFragment i have a RecyclerView that is working fine and is showing the items as intended.

The problem comes, when i insert data using a DialogFragment, because it does insert data (i am using DbFlow ORM), but it does not (of course) refresh the adapter since it is in the TaskFragment fragment inside the DetailMainActivity activity as i said.

I have tried to use onResume() and onPause() in order to refresh the adapter, but they are never called since the activity does not get paused or in onresume for a DialogFragment.

I have tried aswell to use an interface, but it does not work and i have searched all over stackoverflow and google with no luck.

I leave here some of my code for you to understand better:

**DetailMainActivity.java**
Here in the onClick interface i show the DialogFragment to the user to input the information.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                AddSimpleTask sptask = new AddSimpleTask();
                sptask.show(fm, "tag");
```

**TaskFragment.java**
In this fragment i have my RecyclerView

```
private void setupRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        mRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (DetailMainActivity.FAB_Status) {
                    DetailMainActivity.hideFAB();
                    DetailMainActivity.FAB_Status = false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupAdapter() {

 adapter = new DetailMainTaskAdapter(simpleTaskList, this);
    }
```

**AddSimpleTask**
And this is my DialogFragment. I have set a setOnShowListener() in order to avoid the DialogFragment to get dismiss early.

```
@Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        final AlertDialog dialog =(AlertDialog) getDialog();
        if (dialog != null){
            Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Button negativeButton = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

            positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (mEditTextName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() ||
                            mEditTextContent.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() ) {
                        if (mEditTextName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                            mEditTextName.setError("Can not be empty");
                        }

                        if (mEditTextContent.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                            mEditTextContent.setError("Can not be empty");
                        }
                    }else {
                        presenter.beingInsertion(mEditTextName.getText().toString().trim(), mEditTextContent.getText().toString().trim()
                                , foreignId);
                    }
                }
            });

            negativeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

If the insert is successfully achieved the onInsertSuccess method is called (i am using MVP)

```
@Override
    public void onInsertSuccess() {
        Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.containerMainDetail), "Actividad agregada", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        dismiss();
    }
```

I have called adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in many places, and i also tried with a custom interface, but i can not make this work.

Sorry for the long post, but thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your statement but I'll get to that later. `notifyDataSetChanged()` only notifies the adapter that the underlying list (or array) has changed. The implication is that you first need to requery your database and obtain the new list before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter else there is no point as the underlying list will still be the same and it will not update the adapter.

The correct way of calling this will be through your custom listener interface and not in the `onPause()/onResume()` callbacks as there is the possibility that the user does not enter a value and hence you will unnecessarily be querying the database. In your custom listener interface implementation, first update the list with the new data from the DB and then notify the adapter.

Which leads to the error in assumption that `onPause()/onResume()` callbacks do not happen when your Activity is covered by a DialogFragment - this is incorrect. The moment the activity view is even partially covered, the `onPause()` callback is triggered.